# Best approach for HTML5 Progress Bar

Tags: html

I have a page index.php where i ask the user for entering the number of records to store in database. After the request is made, it redirects the user to result.php and echo the execution time. Now i want to print the HTML5 progress bar along with other results.

My Approach(which is not working):

```
for($i=0; $i<$records_to_add; $i++)
    {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO assignment (name, fname, description) VALUES ('osama', 'yawar', 'This is record')");
        $count++;
        $percent = intval($count/$records_to_add * 100)."%";

        echo '<progress min="0" max="'; echo $records_to_add; echo '" value="'; echo $percent; echo'" class="html5">';

    }
```

What is the mistake i am doing? And what can be the best approach? I want to show the progress in the progress bar as well.

Comment: What are you actually looking for?  Assistance with fixing / improving the code that you listed above, or finding a (perhaps) completely different architecture?  Asking for both of them in *one* question isn't really appropriate.

Comment: Well i want to know the solution plus an ideal approach. I did not know asking two questions that are related to each other is inappropriate. Sounds weird !!!

Comment: Hi!  It's because SO is trying to be a great repository of programming knowledge. If a lot of people answered, it would be really confusing.  Some of them would be trying to show you how to improve your code, while others would be about suggesting other, entirely different approaches to implementing progress bars.  When someone stumbles across this question (and the answers) a few years from now, it'll be a complete mishmash of the two.  That's why we shoot for, well, one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two concepts - absolutes and percentages.

Change $percent to $count. Add a closing tag.

```
echo '<progress min="0" max="'; echo $records_to_add; echo '" value="'; echo $count; echo'" class="html5"> </progress>'
```

From https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-progress-element

> To make a determinate progress bar, add a value attribute with the
>   current progress (either a number from 0.0 to 1.0, or, if the max
>   attribute is specified, a number from 0 to the value of the max
>   attribute). To make an indeterminate progress bar, remove the value
>   attribute.